# Swap Histogram of two different images

Tags: opencv, image-processing, histogram

I have two different images (Image A and Image B), whose histograms (histImage and histImage1) i have already computed.
Now I want that the histogram of Image A becomes the histogram of Image B. So that the Image B gets the colors similar to Image A.
 code is as follow:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main( )
{
  Mat src, dst, src1;

  /// Load image
  src = imread("ImageA", 1 );   // Image A
  src1 = imread("ImageB", 1 ); // Image B

  if( !src.data )
    { return -1; }

  /// Separate the image in 3 places ( B, G and R )
  vector<Mat> bgr_planes;
   vector<Mat> bgr_planes1;
  split( src, bgr_planes );
  split( src1, bgr_planes1 );

  /// Establish the number of bins
  int histSize = 256;

  /// Set the ranges ( for B,G,R) )
  float range[] = { 0, 256 } ;
  const float* histRange = { range };

  bool uniform = true; bool accumulate = false;

  Mat b_hist, g_hist, r_hist;  //ImageA
  Mat b_hist1, g_hist1, r_hist1; //ImageB

  /// Compute the histograms of Image A
  calcHist( &bgr_planes[0], 1, 0, Mat(), b_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );
  calcHist( &bgr_planes[1], 1, 0, Mat(), g_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );
  calcHist( &bgr_planes[2], 1, 0, Mat(), r_hist, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );
   /// Compute the histograms of Image B
    calcHist( &bgr_planes1[0], 1, 0, Mat(), b_hist1, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );
  calcHist( &bgr_planes1[1], 1, 0, Mat(), g_hist1, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );
  calcHist( &bgr_planes1[2], 1, 0, Mat(), r_hist1, 1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate );


  // Draw the histograms for B, G and R
  int hist_w = 512; int hist_h = 400;   //Image A
  int bin_w = cvRound( (double) hist_w/histSize ); //Image A
   int hist_w1 = 512; int hist_h1 = 400;  //Image B
    int bin_w1 = cvRound( (double) hist_w1/histSize );//Image B

  Mat histImage( hist_h, hist_w, CV_8UC3, Scalar( 0,0,0) );  //ImageA
    Mat histImage1( hist_h1, hist_w1, CV_8UC3, Scalar( 0,0,0) ); //ImageB

  /// Normalize the result to [ 0, histImage.rows ] ImageA
  normalize(b_hist, b_hist, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );
  normalize(g_hist, g_hist, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );
  normalize(r_hist, r_hist, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );
    /// Normalize the result to [ 0, histImage.rows ] ImageB
    normalize(b_hist1, b_hist1, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );
  normalize(g_hist1, g_hist1, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );
  normalize(r_hist1, r_hist1, 0, histImage.rows, NORM_MINMAX, -1, Mat() );


  /// Draw for each channel  ImageA
  for( int i = 1; i < histSize; i++ )
  {
      line( histImage, Point( bin_w*(i-1), hist_h - cvRound(b_hist.at<float>(i-1)) ) ,
                       Point( bin_w*(i), hist_h - cvRound(b_hist.at<float>(i)) ),
                       Scalar( 255, 0, 0), 2, 8, 0  );
      line( histImage, Point( bin_w*(i-1), hist_h - cvRound(g_hist.at<float>(i-1)) ) ,
                       Point( bin_w*(i), hist_h - cvRound(g_hist.at<float>(i)) ),
                       Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0  );
      line( histImage, Point( bin_w*(i-1), hist_h - cvRound(r_hist.at<float>(i-1)) ) ,
                       Point( bin_w*(i), hist_h - cvRound(r_hist.at<float>(i)) ),
                       Scalar( 0, 0, 255), 2, 8, 0  );
  }
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  /// Draw for each channel  ImageB
  for( int i = 1; i < histSize; i++ )
  {
      line( histImage1, Point( bin_w1*(i-1), hist_h1 - cvRound(b_hist1.at<float>(i-1)) ) ,
                       Point( bin_w1*(i), hist_h1 - cvRound(b_hist1.at<float>(i)) ),
                       Scalar( 255, 0, 0), 2, 8, 0  );
      line( histImage1, Point( bin_w1*(i-1), hist_h1 - cvRound(g_hist1.at<float>(i-1)) ) ,
                       Point( bin_w1*(i), hist_h1 - cvRound(g_hist1.at<float>(i)) ),
                       Scalar( 0, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0  );
      line( histImage1, Point( bin_w1*(i-1), hist_h1 - cvRound(r_hist1.at<float>(i-1)) ) ,
                       Point( bin_w1*(i), hist_h1 - cvRound(r_hist1.at<float>(i)) ),
                       Scalar( 0, 0, 255), 2, 8, 0  );
  }
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  /// Display
  namedWindow("calcHist", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow("face ", histImage );  //Histogram of Image A
   /// Display
  namedWindow("calcHist1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  imshow("body ", histImage1 ); //Histogram of Image B

  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you facing any particular problems with this?

Comment: no, code is working fine up to this point..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207916/how-to-perform-skin-tone-matching
this is what i actually want to achieve... basically i have two images 1) image of a face 2) image of a body.. i want to change the contrast/saturation/whatever of the body image with respect to the face image so that it matches the skin tone

Comment: I would agree with the post on the forum you pointed to. Detect the face or all the skin regions in the first image, and then extract the histogram only for these pixels. Next, detect the skin in the second image and extract the histogram. Finally, swap the histograms as you have done above.

Comment: i have already extracted the skin regions from both the images.... actually i am stuck at the final step, swapping the histograms.. 
 the above code only computes two histograms....

Answer (score 2):

One way to swap the histograms would be to follow the methodology used in [histogram equalisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization).

- Compute the histograms (H1 and H2) respectively for the two images (I1 and I2) and normalise them (already done in your code).
- Compute the cumulative histograms - also called cumulative distribution functions - C1 and C2 corresponding to H1 and H2 as explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization#Small_image).
- Substitute new values for every pixel in I1 using the cumulative histogram C2 as explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization#Small_image).
- Do the same for every pixel in I2, using cumulative histogram C1.